# Determine what user created objects in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm trying to go through our development DB right now and clean up some of the old test procs/tables. Is it possible to determine what user created objects in a SQL Server 2005 database? If so, how would I go about finding that information?

Edit: Just wanted to clarify that the objects in question already exist. Setting up auditing and triggers probably wouldn't do me much good. I guess I was mostly looking for a way to use the system tables/views to get to the information.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The answer is "no, you probably can't".

While there is stuff in there that might say who created a given object, there are a lot of "ifs" behind them. A quick (and not necessarily complete) review:

sys.objects (and thus sys.tables, sys.procedures, sys.views, etc.) has column principal_id. This value is a foreign key that relates to the list of database users, which in turn can be joined with the list of SQL (instance) logins. (All of this info can be found in further system views.)

But.

A quick check on our setup here and a cursory review of BOL indicates that this value is only set (i.e. not null) if it is "different from the schema owner". In our development system, and we've got dbo + two other schemas, everything comes up as NULL. This is probably because everyone has dbo rights within these databases.

This is using NT authentication. SQL authentication probably works much the same. Also, does everyone have *and use* a unique login, or are they shared? If you have employee turnover and domain (or SQL) logins get dropped, once again the data may not be there or may be incomplete.

You can look this data over (select * from sys.objects), but if principal_id is null, you are probably out of luck.

Answer (score 59):

If the object was recently created, you can check the Schema Changes History report, within the SQL Server Management Studio, which "provides a history of all committed DDL statement executions within the Database recorded by the default trace":

[image]

You then can search for the create statements of the objects. Among all the information displayed, there is the login name of whom executed the DDL statement.

Answer (score 20):

If each user has its own SQL Server login you could try this

```
select 
    so.name, su.name, so.crdate 
from 
    sysobjects so 
join 
    sysusers su on so.uid = su.uid  
order by 
    so.crdate
```

Comment: But it appears so.uid is really a SchemaId for non-imported dbs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177596.aspx

Comment: For me it gives me the Role name  not the actual user. The report from @Guillermo Gutiérrez answer gives the actual username.

Comment: As alluded to by @crokusek, for recent versions of SQL Server/Azure SQL database this doesn't work. The notes @crokusek link to state that "For databases upgraded from an earlier version of SQL Server, [`uid` in the `sysobjects` table] is equal to the user ID of the owner" - but this won't be the case if you've just created your database on a recent version of SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

If you need a small and specific mechanism, you can search for [DLL Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186406.aspx) info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the source code sample below to extract this information. You just have to note that in case of loss trace file the latest information is not available, but it is better to regularly maintain the output of this source code in the database by a daily job and your basis should be this table.

```
DECLARE @curr_tracefilename VARCHAR(500); 
DECLARE @indx int ;

DECLARE @base_tracefilename VARCHAR(500); 

DECLARE @path_separator CHAR(1) ;
SET @path_separator = ISNULL(CONVERT(CHAR(1), SERVERPROPERTY('PathSeparator')), '\') ;

SELECT @curr_tracefilename = path FROM sys.traces WHERE is_default = 1 ; 
SET @curr_tracefilename = reverse(@curr_tracefilename)
SELECT @indx  = PATINDEX('%'+@path_separator+'%', @curr_tracefilename) 
SET @curr_tracefilename = REVERSE(@curr_tracefilename)

SET @base_tracefilename = LEFT( @curr_tracefilename,LEN(@curr_tracefilename) - @indx) + @path_separator + 'log.trc';

--insert into @temp_trace 
SELECT ObjectName
,       DatabaseName
,       StartTime
,      CASE  EventClass WHEN 46 THEN 'CREATE' WHEN 47 THEN 'DROP' WHEN 164 THEN 'ALTER' END AS EventClass
,       EventSubClass
,       ObjectType
,       ServerName
,       LoginName
,       ApplicationName
,       'temp' 
FROM ::fn_trace_gettable( @base_tracefilename, DEFAULT ) 
WHERE 
    EventSubclass = 0 
    AND DB_NAME(DatabaseID) NOT IN ('tempdb','msdb','master') 
    AND EventClass in (46,47,164) 
    AND ObjectName is not NULL
```