# Get User ID of view creater and user ID of last modify

Tags: sql, t-sql, view

As per the title, I wanted to know if it's possible to get the userID of the person who created a view and the last person who modified the view

Thanks

Comment: The short answer is no, not in general. Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255947/determine-what-user-created-objects-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

By default the answer is no.  However, you can create a tracking trigger to log this information so you can view it at a later date. [SQL Server Triggers To Track Database Changes](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/) has a good description on how to set it up for stored procedures you can modify this to work for tables and views also.  With that said and as a side note you can look at `select * from information_schema.VIEWS` and `select * from sys.views` to see when the Views were last modified.