# Does SQL Server store the name of the user who originally created a User Defined Function?

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

I need to be able to learn the name of the user who originally created a User Defined Function.

I am able to retrieve the rest of the information on the function using the following code, but sys.objects doesn't have the user id who originally created the function itself:

```
SELECT
*
FROM sys.objects
WHERE object_id = 123456
```

I get the name, date created, last modified, etc, but not the name or identifier of the original user.

Comment: Take a peek at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255947/determine-what-user-created-objects-in-sql-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Partially, if object was created not by the database owner, otherwise you will see a `dbo` as the creator:</strike>

```
USE db;
SELECT so.name AS [ObjectName],
       su.name AS [UserName]
FROM sysobjects so
    JOIN sysusers su
        ON su.uid = so.uid
WHERE so.id = OBJECT_ID('FunctionName');
```

---

Update: Martin Smith comment is correct. Starting from SQL Server 2005:

> By default, when developers create objects in a schema, the objects
>   are owned by the security principal that owns the schema, not the
>   developer. Object ownership can be transferred with ALTER
>   AUTHORIZATION Transact-SQL statement.

Therefore, if ownership specified explicitly, it can be retrieved from sys.objects:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON OBJECT::myFunction TO someUser

-- returns non-null value after transfer:
SELECT principal_id FROM sys.objects WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('myFunction')
```

Otherwise, the newly created object is owned by "schema owner". So there is no way to query who was really the initial owner/creator..

As the last resort a suggestion of @John Cappelletti. His link to similar topic has an answer:

> If the object was recently created, you can check the Schema Changes
>   History report, within the SQL Server Management Studio, which
>   "provides a history of all committed DDL statement executions within
>   the Database recorded by the default trace":

Comment: Thanks! This told me what I need to know.

Comment: This is incorrect, the join on `sysusers` is completely bogus. The correct join would be `SELECT so.name AS [ObjectName],
       s.name AS [SchemaName]
FROM sysobjects so
    JOIN sys.schemas s
        ON s.schema_id = so.uid
WHERE so.id = OBJECT_ID('Foobar.Bar');` because this only returns information about the schema of the object - not who created it.

Comment: See for example https://i.stack.imgur.com/Frpzf.png

Comment: @MartinSmith, thanks for pointing into this misinformation

Answer (score 0):

If every user has its own  LOGIN in SQL Server. You can get it from sysobjects. Check the code below

```
select  so.name, u.name, so.crdate 
from  sysobjects so 
inner join sysusers u 
  on so.uid = u.uid  
order by 
    so.crdate
```

Comment: Thanks! This told me what I need to know.